# Eclipse P2 repository supported on Azure Artifacts(from Azure DevOps)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts, p2

My team decided to migrate to Azure DevOps and want to use Azure Artifacts.

One of the projects we have is a Java Application that relies on **Eclipse P2 Repositories**. I am not really a JAVA expert but as far as I could understand a [P2 Repository](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started), [it combines a metadata repository, used for resolution and an artifact repository, used for finding and collecting artifacts](https://bkapukaranov.wordpress.com/category/tech/p2/).

My question is: Can I use any of the existing options of Azure Artifacts to be my P2 Repository?

I was wondering if I could use "[Universal Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops)", but I think that would be not possible as there`s no direct link to the artifact. :-|

Does anyone faced this situation?

We are trying to refrain adding some other Artifact Management solution like Nexus, JFrog, .. to reduce complexity.

BR
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Azure Artifacts for a hosted p2 repository. The layout of a p2 repository is different from all repository types that Azure Artificats supports like Maven, npm or nuget. Universal Artifacts only let you store single files.

If you want to store your plugins/features you will have to use Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for your answer. We end up using an File Share within an Azure Storage Account to host the P2 artefacts and access them over a mounted network drive when building. Not the best solution, but so far we got satisfactory results.

Comment: Hi PCBL. Nice idea! The p2/Azure Artifacts problem is something I also stumbled across and your solution is clearly easier than setting up a repository server.